# How to count the number of unique products purchased by a user?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a store database with links like this:

[image: ER-diagram]

My task is that I need to display the number of products (unique - those that do not repeat). That is, conditionally, I need to count all the goods purchased by the user, but if I have already counted some goods, do not count it (because it has already been counted).

How can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  o.buyer_id,
  u.first_name || ' ' || u.last_name,
  p.name,
  Sum(po.quantity)
FROM orders o
left JOIN products_to_orders po ON po.order_id = o.id
left JOIN products p ON p.id = po.product_id
left JOIN users u ON u.id = o.buyer_id
GROUP BY o.buyer_id, u.first_name || ' ' || u.last_name, p.name
```

Group by might be scuffed but I can't really test this

EDIT: added aliases

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, when trying to execute the query, an error occurs: `missing FROM-clause entry for table "product_to_orders"`
Could you help me solve it? BUT I understood the idea of your request.

Comment: I do not really use PostgreSQL but it seems like an error related to missing aliases. See edited answer